# Service Fabric StateLessService only instantiating on one node

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I created a brand-new Service Fabric app with a single StatelessService.  I expected the service to be instantiated on all five nodes (see my ApplicationManifest.xml file, below), but for some reason it always instantiates on Node 1.  Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationManifest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ApplicationTypeName="AlgoistsType" ApplicationTypeVersion="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="TradeSafe_ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" DefaultValue="" />
    <Parameter Name="TradeSafe_MinReplicaSetSize" DefaultValue="3" />
    <Parameter Name="TradeSafe_PartitionCount" DefaultValue="1" />
    <Parameter Name="TradeSafe_TargetReplicaSetSize" DefaultValue="3" />
    <Parameter Name="FrontEnd_ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" DefaultValue="" />
    <Parameter Name="FrontEnd_InstanceCount" DefaultValue="-1" />
  </Parameters>
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="TradeSafePkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
    <ConfigOverrides />
    <EnvironmentOverrides CodePackageRef="code">
      <EnvironmentVariable Name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" Value="[TradeSafe_ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT]" />
    </EnvironmentOverrides>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="FrontEndPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
    <ConfigOverrides />
    <EnvironmentOverrides CodePackageRef="code">
      <EnvironmentVariable Name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" Value="[FrontEnd_ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT]" />
    </EnvironmentOverrides>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <DefaultServices>
    <Service Name="FrontEnd" ServicePackageActivationMode="ExclusiveProcess">
      <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="FrontEndType" InstanceCount="[FrontEnd_InstanceCount]">
        <SingletonPartition />
      </StatelessService>
    </Service>
  </DefaultServices>
</ApplicationManifest>
```

Comment: *but for some reason it always instantiates on Node 1* -> how did you determine this?

Comment: By looking in Service Fabric Explorer and seeing that only one node has an instance of my StateLessService type

Comment: If you check the instance count in the Service Fabric Explorer, what is specified there? My guess would be that the ApplicationParameters override your ApplicationManifest.

Comment: Exactly right!  Thank you so much.  It was driving me nuts :)